# Trying to call Watson Translation Service

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I am trying to call the IBM Watson Service via REST call in Java. I have got an Web Project in Eclipse which is published via Bluemix Tools. I also use the .jar Files. But when i´m trying a simple code like:

```
LanguageTranslation service = new LanguageTranslation();
service.setUsernameAndPassword("{username}","{password}");

List <IdentifiedLanguage> langs = service.identify("this is a test");
System.out.println(langs);
```

I get this exception:

```
Unable to extract the trust manager on okhttp3.internal.Platform@ab895790, sslSocketFactory is class com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl
[WARNING ] Application {http://webapp.aw/}ResourceServlet has thrown exception, unwinding now
[WARNING ] Exception in handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSDefaultFaultOutInterceptor@ac51d486
Unable to extract the trust manager on okhttp3.internal.Platform@ab895790, sslSocketFactory is class com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl
Unable to extract the trust manager on okhttp3.internal.Platform@ab895790, sslSocketFactory is class com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl
```

Comment: What kind of credentials are you using for "username" and "password"? Bluemix account or api_key for AlchemyAPI?

Comment: I am using the credentials from the Bluemix account. I use the Translation Language Service, not AlchemyAPI

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk?cm_mc_uid=56417368661114344631188&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1461763559#getting-the-service-credentials). > "Service credentials are different from your Bluemix account username and password"

Comment: Yes, sorry, i meant that i have used the credentials,which i get via Bluemix, from the service.

Comment: seems to be related to SSL. For watson we use https://gateway.watsonplatform.net make sure you can get to that page from your browser and that the JVM has certificates to access that host. I think the problem is that your JVM is not validating the SSL certificates but I could be wrong.

Comment: If you do `cf env <app-name>` verify if the username and pwd of your service is the same that you are using?

Comment: @fscore Yes, its the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some incompatibility with the JVM used on Bluemix and this latest (3.0.0.RC1) version of the library.

I can run the sample code locally just fine.  Just not on Bluemix.

My workaround is to use the older 2.10 version of the library:

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/releases/tag/java-sdk-2.10.0

Everything works fine there (however you need to remove the .execute() from the end of the translate call to be compatible with older library).

Comment: looks like this has been declared as a bug.
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/issues/264

Comment: Thank you very much. The code is now working with the older 2.10 library!

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have an outdated JAR file. Can you try downloading the latest version from [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk#jar).

Once you have done that, add the JAR file to the project's build path, and try this:

```
LanguageTranslation service = new LanguageTranslation();
service.setUsernameAndPassword("username", "password");

ServiceCall<List<IdentifiedLanguage>> langs = service.identify("this is a test");
System.out.println(langs.execute());
```

Comment: Sorry, this didn´t work for me. I get the same exception

Comment: Ok, hmm, can you verify that you are grabbing the username and password from [here](http://i.imgur.com/WBTvUI0.png) and if so, maybe try deleting the service instance and creating a new one.